# BMW E90 pre facelift - REST heat button / fuse

Tags: bmw, fuse, e90

In my E90 I have a REST button:

[image]

It seems not to work, when I press it, the LED won't light and the heating won't work. Could this be a defect fuse? And if yes, which one (could it be 15 and/or 67)?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't know which of two fuses it is, take them both out (remember where they went), and have a look at them! One will clearly be broken if that is the case. If not, you can eliminate that as an answer to your problem. I don't think the fuse box would be very hard to get to in your car.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand and how I've seen it used.

If the ignition is off it uses the residual heat from the engine to warm the car.

In order to validate my claim, turn your car off and hit the button.  You may need to try it with the key in it.

Interested if I'm correct.  Please follow up.   :-)

Comment: Did you give it a try?

Comment: I'll give it a try today and write again, thank you for the information!

Comment: It worked well as I turned off the ignition after a ~15 min ride. When I took out the key and pressed the button, the REST function worked well! Perfect, thank you!

Comment: Excellent.  Glad to hear it.  thanks for awarding the answer.